# OpenCV HOG Algorithm in Real Time on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, raspberry-pi

I would like to know if it is possible to run the OpenCV HOG Detector using a Raspberry Pi in real time using the Raspberry Pi camera.

Comment: not really an answer, but opencv3.0 also has softcascades trained on humans, which run much faster than the hog one

Comment: @berak: You must be a GOD!!!! anyways, what abt Rasbery PI?

Comment: Referring to http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~lav/Papers/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09.html, it seems that real time HOG on a PC needs a GPU. And I don't think OpenCV supports the VideoCoreIV GPU, so I don't like the chances of a 700MHz ARM being able to do this.

Comment: @B...: Yeah, so what about softcascades?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, even overclocked to 1000MHz and with 64MB for video it's not enough.
On my old mac with a 2.1 GHz Dual Core Intel CPU and 2GB of ram I could barely get between 8-12 FPS for a 640x480 stream.

I haven't tried OpenCV 3.0 (just 2.4.8) on Raspberry PI so don't have any softcascades test results to share, but it sounds promising.

Another idea I can think of is using LBP cascades. You could start with a HAAR since there's one already for detecting bodies so it would be easy to test, but LBP should be a bit faster. Perhaps you could train a cascade that works really well for a set environment.

Also, if it helps, you can use my little [OpenCV wrapper for the PiCamera](https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture) for tests. It basically returns frames from the Pi Camera module as `cv::Mat`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply George. When it comes to Softcascades, I need to run for the video input generated from multiple cams in real time. How fast the PC should be?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer above, I hadn't had a chance to use Softcascades myself yet, so I can't give you an answer. However, you can run a test with a single camera, see if you can run in on the GPU as well (not all GPU cards and not all algorithms are supported with OpenCV, so check that first). Based on your tests with a single camera (measuring the time it takes for the detection) you should be able to estimate how long it would take for multiple cameras

Answer (score 0):

I've had openCV running on a PI, using a USB video grabber, as I am using a CCTV camera. I use Python.

It runs fine (for what I want to do), but you need to limit the resolution.

It's slower than a PC (2ghz dual core) but still works.